# When using context.arc, line in middle of circle?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So back to my test page again, http://joeybabcock.me/tests/php/5.php and this time, if you click the circle, it has a line in between it when I try to draw.

```
if(isCircl){
  context.lineWidth = 1;
 context.arc(e.clientX+2, e.clientY-15, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
 context.stroke();
  }else{
```

Is the code that draws it, it is called apon in the drawer3.js file(http://joeybabcock.me/js/drawer3.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer... it should have been:

```
ontext.lineWidth = 1;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(e.clientX+2, e.clientY-15, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```